# type number está permitiendo ingresar caracter "e"

Tags: jquery

Estimados estoy desarrollando y tengo un problema con un input type number creado desde jquery, el problema es que este campo me está permitiendo el ingreso de la letra "e".

```
<script>

        $('#txtSolCursoNombresSolicitud').attr("placeholder","Máximo 4 digitos");
    $('#txtSolCursoNombresSolicitud').attr("type","number");



    $('#txtSolCursoNombresSolicitud').keyup(function()
    {


        if($('#txtSolCursoNombresSolicitud').val().length > 4)
        {
            var mensaje="debe ingresar sólo 3 digitos";


            $('#txtSolCursoNombresSolicitud').css("border","2px solid red");


            $('#btnSaveSolicitudCurso').attr("disabled",true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#btnSaveSolicitudCurso').attr("disabled",false);
            $('#txtSolCursoNombresSolicitud').css("border","1px solid #d6d6d6");
        }


    });

</script>
```

Si se fijan el input está como number desde codigo jquery, pero está aceptando el valor "e".

```
$('#txtSolCursoNombresSolicitud').attr("type","number");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si me pudieran ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso es porque en notación científica puedes ingresar algo como "10e-5".

Para evitar que ingresen algo que no sea un número, puedes agregar esto:

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[type=number]').keypress(function(key) {
        if(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number"/>
```

Suerte!